# Duplicate primary keys created in rails models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, primary-key, has-many-through, model-associations

I am trying to create a chat functionality in my app using Ruby/Rails with React frontend. I am having an issue creating duplicate conversation instances with the same key every time I create a new message that belongs to that conversation.  I have a user, conversation, and message model with the following associations.

User associations:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_secure_password
  validates :username, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  has_many :messages
  has_many :conversations, through: :messages
end
```

Here is my conversation associations:

```
class Conversation < ApplicationRecord
  validates :title, presence: true
  has_many :messages 
  has_many :users, through: :messages
end
```

And here is my message associations:

```
class Message < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :conversation
end
```

Here is the schema for reference:

```
create_table "conversations", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "title"
  t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
end

create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "username"
  t.string "password_digest"
  t.string "avatar"
  t.string "github_username"
  t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
end

create_table "messages", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "content"
  t.integer "user_id"
  t.integer "conversation_id"
  t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
end
```

Then I create a new conversation using the following code in my conversation controller via POST request:

```
def create
    user = User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
    if user
        convo = user.conversations.create!(convo_params)
        render json: convo, status: :created
    else
        render json: {errors: ["No user logged in"]}, status: 401
    end
end

def convo_params
    params.permit(:title)
end
```

This will generate a conversation instance with something like {id: 1, title: "Title Given" }.  The problem then comes when I create a new message.  I use the following code to create a new message:

```
def create
    user = User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
    if user
        message = user.messages.create!(message_params)
        render json: message, status: :created
    else
        render json: {errors: ["No user logged in"]}, status: 401
    end
end

def message_params
    params.permit(:conversation_id, :content)
end
```

However, when the new message is created with params from a POST request of something like {conversation_id: 1, content: "hi"}, another instance of conversation with the same primary key as the initially created conversation is produced.  When I query my conversations database I find two instance of conversation with parameters like {id: 1, title: "Title Given" }.

Comment: Hi Kevin. Do you query your database with your rails console?

Comment: The elephant in the room here that you need to fix first is that you're duplicating your authentication logic all over the place instead of just using a callback which bails early if the user is not logged in and you're doing that instead of actually checking if the record you're creating is valid.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `user.messages.create!` will implicitly create a conversation record - that's just how indirect assocations work. This will also be a new record every time.

A good solution here is to create a nested route so that you're adding messages to a particular conversation instead of just creating the conversation implicitly:

```
resources :conversations do
  resources :messages, only: :create
end
```

```
class MessagesController
  # @todo refactor your auth system so that you're not repeating yourself all over the place 
  # - or better yet don't reinvent the wheel and use a tried and tested solution
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  # POST /conversations/1/messages
  def create
    message = conversation.messages.new(
      message_params.merge(user: current_user) # @todo implement this method
    )
    if message.save
      render json: message, status: :created
    else
      render json: { errors: message.errors.full_messages }, 
             status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  private 

  def conversation
    @conversation ||= Conversation.find(params[:conversation_id])
  end

  def message_params
     params.require(:message)
           .permit(:foo, :bar, :baz)
  end
end
```

This will require you to alter your javascript code so that you use the id of the conversation that you previously created in the URL. You'll also need a way to lookup conversations so that users can add new messages later - for example after closing the tab.

This isn't the only way to solve the problem - you could also see if a conversation exists when creating the message or create it implicily - but this really is an entire question on its own.